# What's the technical name for the selector menu that pops out on apps like WhatsApp?

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios, xamarin

what is the correct name for the following menu? I need to create it using Monotouch but I have no idea how to refer to it.

[image: PopUp menu]

Comment: I'm sure this 'duplicate' question was not asked of this specific screenshot..?  How then is it a duplicate question and not a 'similar question' ?

Answer (score 3):

It is called an [Action Sheet](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/standard_controls/actionsheet/display_an_actionsheet/).